# How to identify text visibilty on a label

Tags: c#, winforms, coded-ui-tests

I am doing coded-ui automation of AUT and finding all children controls from window and then have to filter non visible controls

I tried with uicontrol.state it returns"Readonly" and bounding rect is also positive, can not use trygetclickablepoint as it filters even visible controls?

please suggest some approach

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem, you want know if the control is Visible ?

So you can use :

```
this.myControl.Visible
```

Return **TRUE** or **FALSE**

Comment: Visible property is not exposed to codedui...cant use it

Answer (score 0):

If it's a winforms application you can use the AccessibleState of the control to determine if it's visible or not.

```
Accessibility.IAccessible acc = (myControl.NativeElement as object[])[0] as Accessibility.IAccessible;
bool isVisible = ((int)acc.accState & (int)AccessibleStates.Invisible) == 0;
```

Include Accessibility dll first.

I'd also encourage you to only use Accessibility to go through the children of the window using accNavigate or AccessibleChildren (oleacc.dll). CUIT converts all MSAA objects to UITestControls first, slowing the process down. And by slow, I mean HELLA SLOW.

### EDIT:

Looked into it again and I forgot to mention that the label itself won't have the invisible state but the window containing the label. And CUIT can tell if a window is invisible or not so you don't actually need Accessibility for this task. The CUIT solution would be something like this:

```
bool isVisible = !myControl.GetParent().State.HasFlag(ControlStates.Invisible);
```

So short answer is: check visibility state on container window and not the label control itself.

Comment: already tried it returns focusable state,but can't see the controls with eyes. even parent static window state is focusable and control state is readonly

Comment: Well MSAA visibility doesn't exactly mean the same as visible to the eyes. If an element is off screen it will be invisible. If it's in the middle of your form but blocked by another control it will still be visible for MSAA. You could try hit testing to check if anything overlaps your texts but you said that didn't really work out. As a last resort you can try to call the texts' 'CaptureImage' method and do optical character recognition on the images. There are some free OCR applications out there, tho I don't have any experience with them myself.